# Fastest way to try out a new library in a REPL using Leinengen with Clojure

Tags: clojure

New clojure developer trying to experiment with the [HTTP kit clojure library](http://www.http-kit.org/client.html) in a REPL.

I created a new project in leinengen, `lein new app kit-expt`.

Then I modified the :dependencies block in project.clj to include `[http-kit "2.2.0"]`.

Then I run `lein deps`, then `lein repl`.

In the REPL I try to run `(:require [org.httpkit.client :as http])`.

However, when I run this I get the error

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.httpkit.client, compiling:(/private/var/folders/cs/b0kcg6fx0335crbvn6xtgq7xl5c29j/T/form-init7575648818353088270.clj:1:1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd actually suggest that the fastest way doesn't involve `lein new` at all. See [lein-try](https://github.com/rkneufeld/lein-try). Once installed in your `~/.lein/profiles.clj`, `lein try http-kit 2.2.0` -> working REPL.

Comment: If it's an option to use [Boot](http://boot-clj.com/) instead of Leiningen, you can simply use the command `boot -d http-kit:2.2.0 repl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be something wrong in your environment.  If I run it (Ubuntu 16.04) it works great:

```
(require '[org.httpkit.client :as http])
(pr-str (clojure.core/deref (http/get "http://google.com")))) 

   => "{:opts {:method :get, :url \"http://www.google.com/\", :query-params nil, :form-params nil, :trace-re".....
```

## Update

As Micah pointed out, in the repl you need the above form of `require`. Notice that it doesn't have the leading colon, and it does have a single-quote before the left square bracket. It must also be inside parentheses instead of square brackets.

In the `ns` form (which I prefer), everything has the opposite convention:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [org.httpkit.client :as http]  ))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:require` form you're using is invalid, a keyword only for use in an `ns` (namespace) form. Try removing the `:` and just use `(require ...`, which is commonly used in a REPL.  See more `require` examples [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require).

The HTTP Client docs you refer to assume you're in a source file using [ns](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns).